# turn cURL json array response to an associate array

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a cURL request like so

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = 'filter=year(StartTime)' . urlencode(' eq 2013 and ') .'month(StartTime)'. urlencode(' eq 06') ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url.com/id()/events?$".$data);
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'X-ApiKey : XXXXXXXXXX'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response, true);

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


</head>

<body>

<br><br>
<?php 
 echo "the name". $result['Name'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what it prints.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Length: 218 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET- WEBSRV X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET - ARR02 Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2013 02:52:31 GMT [{"Id":1079,"Name":"Test ","Status":1,"MemberId":1308,"Description":"This is a Test Event","SponsoredBy":null,"StartTime":"2013-06-30T12:00:00","EndTime":"2013-06-30T23:59:00","SearchDescription":null,"Types":[1,4,6]}] 

the name
```

How can I put this into a Associative array?

I've tried this

```
json_decode($response,true));
```

and this

```
ksort($response);
```

and this

```
var_dump($response);
```

and nothing seems to work..

I want to be able to output like this

```
echo $reponse['Name'];
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: You mention that `var_dump($response);` "doesn't work" - what does it give you? Are you struggling to get the JSON string from the CURL call, or struggling to decode it into an array?

Comment: If I do this ` $response = var_dump($response); echo $response['Name'];` in outputs this `bool(true)` It seems to get the json string from CURL fine.. just can't get it into a assoc array

Comment: @IMSoP I think it has something to do with my return string. Some of the values are ints and arrays that don't have quotes around them. Do you know how I could handle this? Could that be the problem?

Comment: `json_decode($response,true));` worked for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default curl_exec outputs the data it gets from the server to the standard output so your $response variable doesn't really have the actual response data in it. If you want to get the data in a variable set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option before calling curl_exec.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 16):

`json_decode` gives you an associative array when [you pass "true" as the second argument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
  $json = '[{"Id":1079,"Name":"Test ","Status":1,"MemberId":1308,"Description":"This is a Test Event","SponsoredBy":null,"StartTime":"2013-06-30T12:00:00","EndTime":"2013-06-30T23:59:00","SearchDescription":null,"Types":[1,4,6]}]';

  $response = json_decode($json, true);

  echo $response[0]["Name"];
```

gives:

```
Test
```

**Edit:**

`json_decode()` is giving you back an array of arrays, so you need to reference the array that is at position `[0]` in the response, if you get me.

I've done that above in my example with $response[0], but have a look at this example, hope it makes it clearer!

```
  $result = json_decode($json, true);
  var_dump($result);
```

gives:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["Id"]=>
    int(1079)
    ["Name"]=>
    string(5) "Test "
    ["Status"]=>
    int(1)
    ["MemberId"]=>
    int(1308)
    ["Description"]=>
    string(20) "This is a Test Event"
    ["SponsoredBy"]=>
    NULL
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(19) "2013-06-30T12:00:00"
    ["EndTime"]=>
    string(19) "2013-06-30T23:59:00"
    ["SearchDescription"]=>
    NULL
    ["Types"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(4)
      [2]=>
      int(6)
    }
  }
}
```

then.. to access the array itself:

```
  $result = json_decode($json, true);

  $result = $result[0]; // let's just reassign this to get the array we want      
  var_dump($result);
```

gives:

```
array(10) {
  ["Id"]=>
  int(1079)
  ["Name"]=>
  string(5) "Test "
  ["Status"]=>
  int(1)
  ["MemberId"]=>
  int(1308)
  ["Description"]=>
  string(20) "This is a Test Event"
  ["SponsoredBy"]=>
  NULL
  ["StartTime"]=>
  string(19) "2013-06-30T12:00:00"
  ["EndTime"]=>
  string(19) "2013-06-30T23:59:00"
  ["SearchDescription"]=>
  NULL
  ["Types"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(4)
    [2]=>
    int(6)
  }
}
```

And now you can access the various elements of the array directly:

```
  $result = json_decode($json, true);
  $result = $result[0];

  echo "Name: ". $result["Name"] . "\nID:   " . $result["Id"] . "\nDescription: " . $result["Description"] . "\n";
```

now we get back:

```
Name: Test 
ID:   1079
Description: This is a Test Event
```

hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

So I have a cURL result like this.

```
{
  "object": "transaction",
  "status": "paid",
}
```

So I did this.

```
$result = json_decode($response, true);
$result['status'];
```

The result will be:

```
paid
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've found is to remove all the header part of the response, find the position of the first character of the json response in your case is '[' but could also be '{', and do this:

```
$json = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Length: 218 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET- WEBSRV X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET - ARR02 Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2013 02:52:31 GMT [{"Id":1079,"Name":"Test ","Status":1,"MemberId":1308,"Description":"This is a Test Event","SponsoredBy":null,"StartTime":"2013-06-30T12:00:00","EndTime":"2013-06-30T23:59:00","SearchDescription":null,"Types":[1,4,6]}] ';
$pos = strpos($json,'[');
$json = substr($json,$pos);
$php_array = json_decode($json, true);
echo "Name= ".$php_array[0]['Name']; //because it starts with [ you need to add [0]
```

And you get
Name= Test