# PHP while loop curl_exec

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, foreach

I am working on creating div for each result coming from `curl_exec` json GET request. I have tried the code below using cURL in PHP. When I run this code nothing comes from the `foreach`.

```
    //API Url
    $url = 'https://api.clover.com:443/v3/merchants/'.$merchantid.'/categories/';

    //Initiate cURL.
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$authtoken.' ',
    );

    //Tell cURL that we want to send a GET request.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

    //Set the content type to application/json
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    //Execute the request
    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    $respArray = json_decode($resp, true);

    foreach($respArray as $key => $value) {
      echo $key . " : " . $value;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

This returns the following:

```
   {
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "QWS8MSMAT49E6",
          "name": "Other",
          "sortOrder": 2
        },
        {
          "id": "35K000MJVVFHE",
          "name": "Pizza",
          "sortOrder": 1
        }
      ],
      "href": "http://api.clover.com/v3/merchants/{[MID]}/categories?limit=100"
    }
```

I'm trying to get the information above into a div, for example:

[image: example output]

Comment: Do u get any error or notice? It looks like u process the array `$respArray` in the foreach loop. But you should apply `$respArray["elements"]`.

Comment: @LucaJung I have just checked PHP log and found `PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. When you say I should apply `$respArray["elements"]` what do you mean? where the change will be on my code? I am might missing the point of it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($respArray);`? I mean change this line `foreach($respArray as $key => $value)` to `foreach($respArray["elements"] as $key => $value)`.

Comment: @LucaJung Getting `int(1)` from `var_dump($respArray);`

Comment: If you get `int(1)` back, where do you get the returning information from?

Comment: @LucaJung tried `$respArray["elements"]` no luck yet

Comment: @LucaJung `curl_exec($ch)` is printing this returning information

Comment: Yes, because you don't have the expected information in the array `$respArray`.

Comment: that "response array" obviously isn't an "array" ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler but is `json_decode` converting `json` to `array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue with adding

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
```

To the code. As has been explained [Here (by Mihai)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17401836/2896031)

> "*By default curl_exec outputs the data it gets from the server to the
>   standard output so your $response variable doesn't really have the
>   actual response data in it. If you want to get the data in a variable
>   set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option before calling curl_exec.*"

And [Martin Zeitler's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54173337/2896031) Answer was right with removing `true` from `json_decode()`

Answer (score 0):

think it works like this:

```
$data = json_decode($resp);
foreach($data->elements as $element) {
  echo '<div id="group_'.$element->id.'" class="product_group">'.$element->name.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: This is still returning nothing. And PHP log still showing `PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @Profile this most likely is because of `json_decode($resp, true)`. most easy would be to use `xdebug` and then set a break-point after the `json_decode()` instruction. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: You was right with removing `TRUE` from `json_decode()` . With setting `RETURNTRANSFER TRUE` and removing `TRUE` from `json_decode` did work. Thank you!